# Kiel traduki Esperante tiun ĉi ludkarton?

Tags: translation

Mi designas Artkartajn Magik' La Renkontiĝo kartojn kaj mi ne scias kiel traduki tiujn frazojn. Tre dankon amikoj! [image: reala karto]

Answer (score 8):

> **Ĉasita Ĉaŭsto**
>
> Kreaĵo — Bruto
>
> Kiam Ĉasita Ĉaŭsto enludiĝas, ĉiu alia ludisto rajtas enludigi
>   kreaĵokarton de sia mano.
>
> *Nur unu sufiĉas por nutri dekdu homojn dum monato*

Mi tradukis "Hunted Wumpus" per "Ĉasita Ĉaŭsto", ĉar mi kredas, ke "Wumpus" tiel nomiĝas, simple ĉar la nomo iel sone similas al "Hunted". Oni ŝanĝu la nomon laŭvole.

Comment: But it's a very odd name for such a beast, since *ĉasto* already has a meaning which is incongruous in this context. (I can't imagine that a *Hunted Wumpus* behaves in a particularly chaste manner!)
http://vortaro.net/#%C4%89asta

Comment: Ho! Mi serĉis ĝin en pli malgranda vortaro, kio ne enhavas la vorton. Cetere, mi eĉ pensas, ke ĝi *tro* sonsimilas. Mi ŝanĝu ĝin, eble al Ĉaŭsto?

Comment: Devus esti dekdu, ne dudek. Mi provis sanĝi ĝin, sed mi ne povis.

Comment: @esperblue: Dankon, iel mi forgesis kion mi tradukis, dum mi tradukis :)